# Django Modeltranslation: TranslationAdmin class does not copy the correct widget

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

I`m using a custom form for a django admin model with translated fields. But the widget of the form is not used. My code:

models.py

```
class Fact(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

translation.py

```
class FactTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('heading')

translator.register(Fact, FactTranslationOptions)
```

admin.py

```
class FactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fact
        widgets = { 
            'heading': forms.Textarea
        }

class FactAdmin(translationadmin.TranslationAdmin):  
    form = FactForm  

admin.site.register(Fact, FactAdmin)
```

With this code, the field heading does not show up as textarea. It`s a default input field.

When I change FactForm to:

```
class FactForm(ProductDataInlineFormBase):
    class Meta:
        model = Fact
        widgets = { 
            'heading_de': forms.Textarea,
            'heading_en': forms.Textarea
        }
```

the textarea widget is used.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in django modeltranslation?

Answer (score 2):

My workaround until this is fixed:

```
def helper_get_translated_widgets(field_names, widget):
    widgets = {}

    for name in field_names:
        for key, value in settings.LANGUAGES:
            widgets["{}_{}".format(name, key)] = widget

    return widgets

class FactForm(ProductDataInlineFormBase):
    class Meta:
        model = Fact
        widgets = {
            **helper_get_translated_widgets(["text"], TinyMCE(mce_attrs=settings.TINYMCE_TABLE_CONFIG)),
            **helper_get_translated_widgets(["heading"], forms.Textarea),
        }
```